# r archive files matching a regex

Tags: regex, r

Ho to archive only files that matched a given regex pattern? If no file meets the pattern, no file should be added to the archive.

I need to get all the files of a directory that matches a string which is the value of a variable:

```
a <- "file-05-02-2014"

files <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = a)
```

In the variable files, I'm getting all the files in the working directory and not only those matching the pattern of the string a.

When I just put the string as a parameter it is worokin fine.

```
files <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "file-05-02-2014")
```

However, I need it to work with a string variable and not a string literal.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the whole context:
I'm calling list.files inside the zip function. When no file matches the pattern, all files and directories inside the specified directory are added to the archive.

```
a <- "file-05-02-2014"
zip(paste(getwd(), "myarchive.zip", sep="/"), 
   files=paste(getwd(), list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = a), sep="/"))
```

So it has to do with zip function and not list.files function.

A solution would be to check if there is any file that meets the pattern before calling zip

```
a <- "file-05-02-2014"
files.to.be.archived <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = a)

if(length(files.to.be.archived)>0)

   zip(paste(getwd(), "myarchive.zip", sep="/"), 
       files=paste(getwd(),files.to.be.archived, sep="/"))
```

Any concise way to do it?

Comment: May be using `glob2rx`

Comment: I tried it ... but it is not working! ... I'm adding more detrails to reflect the context of my case

Comment: If you want people to help you need to add more details and an example of the type of file you need to match.

Comment: Can you give an example of a two files : one wanted and another one you don't want based on `a` (`file-05-02-2014`)

Comment: I don't want files that ends with other dates such as "file-03-02-2014 " to be returned.

Comment: This should work fine, there would be no need to adjust it. The problem may be something else, and not in the regex.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I created two files (`file-03-02-2014` and `file-05-02-2014`) and `list.files(path = mypath, pattern = "file-05-02-2014")` gives the right file

Comment: Yes ... as I said in the update, string literal is OK, but when I use a string variable is not working... I'm goint to check it again.

Comment: The string variable works just fine, the problem is something else.

Comment: Does `a` contain a single character string?

Comment: So, y're right #carloscinelli .. the problem is somewhere else! I checked it again: the problem is when there is no match to the pattern. In such a case the other function I'm using compresses all files and directories inside the working directory (I updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. You can remove the `getwd`s and `paste`s since you are using your working directory only.

```
a <- "file-05-02-2014"
files.to.be.archived <- list.files(pattern = a)
if(length(files.to.be.archived)) 
  zip("myarchive.zip", files = files.to.be.archived)
```